# What priorities can be used in cgroups net_prio module?

Tags: networking, cgroups

Cgroups has a module called `net_prio`, and by using this module I can set the priority of network traffic generated by various applications. As you can read [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_prio.txt), this can be achieved by setting something similar to the following:

```
echo "eth0 5" > /sys/fs/cgroups/net_prio/iscsi/net_prio.ifpriomap
```

But there's no info as to what range of priorities I can use.

Let's say there's a program in my system that should have the lowest network priority. What should I use in the pace of 5 ? Are the priorities similar to `nice` priorities?

Answer (score 1):

From the Kernel documentation titled: [Network priority cgroup](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_prio.txt).

*excerpt*

> #### net_prio.prioidx
>
> This file is read-only, and is simply informative.  It contains a unique integer value that the kernel uses as an internal representation of this cgroup.
>
> #### net_prio.ifpriomap
>
> This file contains a map of the priorities assigned to traffic originating from
>   processes in this group and egressing the system on various interfaces. It
>   contains a list of tuples in the form <ifname priority>.  Contents of this file
>   can be modified by echoing a string into the file using the same tuple format.
>   for example:
>
> ```
>    echo "eth0 5" > /sys/fs/cgroups/net_prio/iscsi/net_prio.ifpriomap
> ```
>
> This command would force any traffic originating from processes belonging to the iscsi net_prio cgroup and egressing on interface eth0 to have the priority of said traffic set to the value 5. The parent accounting group also has a
>   writeable 'net_prio.ifpriomap' file that can be used to set a system default
>   priority.

I believe these priorities work where the higher the number, the higher the precedence. From the `tc` man page:

*excerpt*

```
   PRIO   The  PRIO  qdisc  is  a non-shaping container for a configurable 
          number of classes which are dequeued in order. This allows for 
          easy prioritization of traffic, where lower  classes  are
          only  able  to  send  if higher ones have no packets available. To 
          facilitate configuration, Type Of Service bits are honored by      
          default.
```

So if there are packets for a lower class they have to wait until there aren't any from a higher numbered class.

#### References

- [3.9. net_prio - Red Hat documentation portal](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/net_prio.html)

Comment: I think I figured that out, I mean, how to set the lowest priority to a specific program. In `cgroups/net_prio/net_prio.ifpriomap` I had to set, for example, `eth0 3`, so the default priority of all processes is `3`, and now in a child directory I can easily specify `1` to that program I wanted. Do you know the biggest value the priority may take? There was something about SO_PRIORITY, and this could be 0-6, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - I do not know the upper end value either, but did see that same note, so I would assume that those are the valid range of values.